# How to always show file size on the new Windows 7 Status Bar?

Tags: windows-7

Okay, I just discovered this morning when I tried to see how much space I would gain be emptying my recycle bin that the Status Bar no longer tells you the size of the files selected.... Also if you select a group of file types with various extensions you get a status bar like this....

[image]

Okay, I'll bite.  *clicks*..."Show more details"

[image]

They could display anything here and it would be better than the date modified.

I noticed if the file extensions, (*.sys) for example, are all the same and you don't select too many you get a useful status bar

[image]

There has to be a config change to make this last screenshot the default for all regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think so - that's how it works in Windows 7 and I imagine it will stay that way. Purely in terms of the Recycle Bin, I don't think looking at the properties is the end of the world but if you tend to do a lot of checking in Explorer for file sizes I could see it being a pain.

Comment: Actually, you might need to change the question text as it's subjective and doesn't indicate the actual information you're after.

Answer (score 1):

You could try highlighting the files and selecting `Alt + Enter` to view the properties.

Unfortunately this has been brought up time and time again on different forums and its something that Microsoft really need to fix.

i suggest using [Classic Shell](http://classicshell.sourceforge.net/). This program emulates the old XP bar and will show you all necessary information

Comment: good answer, but add-ins like that, reminds me of the days of windows 95, where you needed 10,000 third party apps to make windows behave.

Comment: Could give it a try, it has a small footprint and could solve your issue

Answer (score 0):

Try dragging the top edge of the blue bar up, it gets bigger and shows more details and from what I've seen it can only show date created/modified and file size of selection.

Comment: Not quite. If you select more than 15 items, then it says *Show more details…* instead of showing any information no matter how big the status pane is.